# Как вывести в context['title'] страницу из paginate_by (listview), чтоб было Сайт -> Страница: 2?

Tags: python, django, pagination

Всем привет, хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так, чтоб при условии, что мы находимся на 2 странице, нам выводилось в {{title}} в ListView "Сайт -> Страница: 2"

Именно начинать выводить со второй страницы

```
class HomeListView(ListView):
context_object_name = 'posts'
paginate_by = 9
template_name = 'modules/posts/post_list_filter.html'
queryset = Post.objects.all()
filterset = PostSortingFilter

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = _('Последние материалы на сайте') + ' | Flowmods'
    context['filter'] = self.filterset
    context['meta_description'] = _('На нашем сайте вы сможете найти самые отборные модификации для Kenshi, Rimworld, S.T.A.L.K.E.R. 2, TES, Fallout, The Sims. А также другие полезные статьи, гайды и прохождения')
    return context

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super().get_queryset()
    filterset = self.filterset(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    return filterset.qs.distinct()
```

Comment: Не до конца понимаю. Вы хотите что бы выводился номер текущей страницы пагинации?

Comment: Да, просто текущий номер страницы пагинации в <title></title>. Сейчас у меня выводится Последние материалы на сайте | Flowmods, но хотелось бы Последние материалы на сайте | Flowmods >> Page 2

Comment: Вроде бы page_obj.number, вот почитайте: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/

Comment: Благодарю, это и вправду то что надо!